# Django dynamic pages. Why is my code not working?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I am creating a website for the sale of goods, and for each product I create a card based on data from the database. When a new card appears, a dynamic page based on the same database data should be automatically connected to it. The page is created, but the data from the model is not loaded. I watched the Django guide, and it showed this method using DetailView, from where I took the code. Please help me, I don't understand what the problem is.

```
My code:

views.py:

class car(DetailView):
    model = inventory
    template_name = 'main/cars.html'
    context_object_name = 'inventory'

urls.py:

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('inventory/<int:pk>', views.car.as_view(), name='cars'),
]

cars.html:

{% extends 'main/layout.html' %}

{% block main %}
{% for el in invent %}
        <div class="main-card ">
            <img  src = '{{ el.img_1 }}' style="">
            <h3 style="">{{ el.name }}</h3>
            <h4 style="">{{ el.rent }}</h4>
            <button><a href="{% url 'cars' el.id %}">Details</a></button>
        </div>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}

models.py:

class inventory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Name', max_length=100)
    type = models.CharField('Type of car', max_length=6)

    img_1 = models.ImageField(upload_to='sql_imgs/')
    img_2 = models.ImageField(upload_to='sql_imgs/')
    img_3 = models.ImageField(upload_to='sql_imgs/')
    img_4 = models.ImageField(upload_to='sql_imgs/')
    img_5 = models.ImageField(upload_to='sql_imgs/')
    img_6 = models.ImageField(upload_to='sql_imgs/')
    img_7 = models.ImageField(upload_to='sql_imgs/')
    img_8 = models.ImageField(upload_to='sql_imgs/')

    MSRP = models.CharField('msrp', max_length=40)
    Purchase = models.CharField('purchase', max_length=40)
    rent = models.CharField('rent', max_length=40)

    specs = models.TextField('specs')

    text = models.TextField('About car')


    def str(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Inventory'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Inventory'
```

I've read a lot of articles, and I haven't found anything worthwhile. I hope I can find the answer here.

Comment: For better practice all your class name should be in CamelCase. 
In your `urls.py` how you are importing the views? please add that for reference.

Comment: @MohammadGolamDostogir Thanks, I'll keep it in mind in the future. Here is the import from urls.py:

from . import views

Comment: In your model `ImageField` modify the upload_to like this without ./`models.ImageField(upload_to='sql_imgs/')` and give it a try

Comment: I am providing you a answer with a properly formatted code can you please use that? and lets fix it from there.

Comment: @MohammadGolamDostogir Thank you very much, everything is working! I didn't think that the loop could break the site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Please update your code like this:**

`models.py`

```
from django.db import models

class Inventory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Name', max_length=100)
    type = models.CharField('Type of car', max_length=6)
    img_1 = models.ImageField(upload_to='sql_imgs/')
    img_2 = models.ImageField(upload_to='sql_imgs/')
    img_3 = models.ImageField(upload_to='sql_imgs/')
    img_4 = models.ImageField(upload_to='sql_imgs/')
    img_5 = models.ImageField(upload_to='sql_imgs/')
    img_6 = models.ImageField(upload_to='sql_imgs/')
    img_7 = models.ImageField(upload_to='sql_imgs/')
    img_8 = models.ImageField(upload_to='sql_imgs/')
    MSRP = models.CharField('msrp', max_length=40)
    Purchase = models.CharField('purchase', max_length=40)
    rent = models.CharField('rent', max_length=40)
    specs = models.TextField('specs')
    text = models.TextField('About car')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Inventory'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Inventories'
```

`views.py`

```
from django.views.generic.detail import DetailView
from .models import Inventory

class CarDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Inventory
    template_name = 'main/cars.html'
    context_object_name = 'inventory'
```

`urls.py`

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import CarDetailView

urlpatterns = [
    path('inventory/<int:pk>/', CarDetailView.as_view(), name='cars'),  # Added trailing slash for best practice
]
```

`cars.html`

```
{% extends 'main/layout.html' %}

{% block main %}
<div class="main-card">
    <img src="{{ inventory.img_1.url }}" alt="{{ inventory.name }}">
    <h3>{{ inventory.name }}</h3>
    <h4>{{ inventory.rent }}</h4>
    <p>{{ inventory.text }}</p>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Please update your code like this and lets see what happens next to fix it as needed.